# Google Maps GOverviewMapControl() and GAdsManager

Tags: maps

I have a GMap2 object with a GOverviewMapControl and a GAdsManager, but they both appear in the lower right hand corner.

How can I get them to appear in different parts of the map?

Here's my Overview:

```
    map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
map.addControl(new GOverviewMapControl());
map.enableDoubleClickZoom();
```

here's my Ads

```
   var adsManagerOptions = {
    maxAdsOnMap: 2,
    style: 'adunit',
    channel: 'XXXXXXXXX'
};

adsManager = new GAdsManager(map, publisherID, adsManagerOptions);
adsManager.enable();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [position property of the GAdsManagerOptions class](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GAdsManagerOptions) will allow you to set the position of the GAdsManager.  The options are passed in to the GAdsManager constructor.

Unfortunately, the [GOverviewMapControl](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GControlImpl.GOverviewMapControl) is not as flexible.  According to the documentation, "Unlike other controls, you can only place this control in the bottom right corner of the map (G_ANCHOR_BOTTOM_RIGHT)."

I have no way to test this at the moment, but your options will probably look something like:

```
   var adsManagerOptions = {
    maxAdsOnMap: 2,
    style: 'adunit',
    channel: 'XXXXXXXXX',
    position: new GControlPosition(G_ANCHOR_BOTTOM_LEFT)
};
```